# How to create a grouped buttons in Tailwinds CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to create something this input layout with Tailwind CSS, but I don't seem to find that Tailwind CSS would support this by default.

[image]

How do I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inline-flex` on the parent div then place border radius on first and last corners using the radius classes `rounded-l-md` => *first button left side with medium radius*, then `rounded-r-md` on the last button => *last button right side with medium radius*.

Add `border` for first and last buttons, center button add only *top* and *bottom* border. ***border*** will be 1 pixel wide border.

Then a variation of border-color-number to get border colors, background-colors, hover-colors, font wieght and size, etc...

You can see their [documentation](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/) which is well documented with examples. Check the side bar on the left for quick browsing.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss-jit-cdn"></script>
<div class="inline-flex">
  <button class="bg-transparent text-md hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-8 border border-gray-400 hover:border-transparent rounded-l-md">
    Text Input
  </button>
  <button class="bg-transparent text-md hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-8 border-t border-b border-gray-400 hover:border-transparent">
    Text Input
  </button>
  <button class="bg-gray-300 text-md hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-6 border border-gray-400 hover:border-transparent rounded-r-md flex justify-between items-center">
    <span class="flex-initial">Select Box</span>

    <svg class="h-4 mx-3 flex-initial fill-current text-blue" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129 129" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 129 129">
      <g>
        <path d="m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```